# Hosting a non core sub-site inside a core 2.0 site error HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

Tags: web-hosting, windows-server-2012-r2, asp.net-core-2.0, subapplication

I just updated my .net web application to .net core 2.0 which runs just fine. There is a sub-site which is a non-core web application. This sub-application is throws an error now: "core 2.0 site error HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure."

I changed the application pool settings to no managed code and explicitly removed the handler for dotnetcore as well.

If I keep the .NET CLR version to old v4..., the sub application loads but then it can't find any of the css files or js files in the sub-application folder.

Will appreciate any help here.

Thanks!

So I created a different application pool for the sub application with CLR version as v4, and now it loads. But it can't find any css files or js files. I am getting a status 502 (Bad Gateway) for all these files. 
FOr example:

AppA: Main  .net core 2 web app
SubAppB: .net 4.6 web app.

On going to https://www.AppA.com/SubAppB/Account/Login
All the images, css, js files are throwing 502. In chrome, I see the the browser looking for the files at location: https://www.AppA.com/SubAppB/Content/login.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All good now. After assigning a different app pool, I had to explicityly remove the main app's handler from the sub application, and it works fine! Hopefully it will help somebody else.